# PHP responding to ajax when running process

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to get some data from Ajax request when already PHP running a long script ;

but when the Ajax has been answered that script in PHP is completed, and I need to get Ajax response during running other scripts .

**JS**

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.post( 'progress.php','',
    function(data){
        $('.-info-').html(data);
    }); 
},100);
```

**progress.php**

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['progress'].'%';
```

**running.php**

```
session_start();
$i=0;
while($i<99){
    $i++;
    $_SESSION['progress'] = $i;
    //sleep(1);
    //flush();
}
```

Is there any way to response when `"while"` is running?

Comment: wow, wow, see update for my answer

Comment: Writes about `$_SESSION` to disk don't happen till the end of the process. The Session file is anyways locked to the *serving process*, which means the **progress.php** process will hang till **running.php** finishes. You'll have to write the progress to your own file and read from there in **progress.php**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Marc B is right. The session will be locked and not updated as required. So you need to store the progress in an system you can access asynchronously from multiple connections - maybe the database?

**running.php:**

```
session_start();
$i=0;
while($i<99){
    $i++;
    // Store progress in Database
}
```

**progress.php:**

```
 session_start();
 //read progress from Database
```

Comment: I tested all answers , so I got that storing into Database is easy and better .tanQ

Comment: I have using progress for copying ,by saving progress in Database and read it by Ajax ... that works fine **for small files**. but when I chose a file (about more than 100MB) to copy , after a few seconds the all `Ajax`s not working .can you help please ? sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1):

use  flush() to send output to browser and onreadystatechange to get response at client side

```
$i=0;
while($i<99){
    $i++;
    echo $i; 
    flush();
    sleep(1);
}
```

an onreadystatechange will be call on every portion of wata from your script  ( http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp )

you should check state 3 - State 3  LOADING Downloading; responseText holds partial data. so you easily can use it - you can check it here developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: did you notice which script is he calling from jquery and which one is locking the session file?

Comment: `onreadystatechange` is fired when the *state* of the connection changes - *not* when the content of the page changes.

Comment: if he'll be print out current status - there is no need to use session - so he can just close session and work with data independently

Comment: and state changed on every portion of data wile page loading

Comment: @VasilVanchuk There is *no* content Available, until you hit readystate 4 and status 200. And then you would know its `100%` without even reading the content.

Comment: you should not wait readystate 4 and status 200 - this is markers that page already loaded. But you cat track state 3  ( http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp )

Comment: State 3 LOADING Downloading; responseText holds partial data. so you easily can use it - you can check it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: well, you are somewhat right. but this will fail for many browsers... IE does not support it at all: `Remarks
You cannot call the responseText property to obtain partial results (readyState = 3). Doing so will return an error, because the response is not fully received. You must wait until all data has been received. ` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534361(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: yep, it's true. But we can just count every state 3 ( as flag that server side send some data ). But as i see - topic starter already got answer. So we can finish discussion

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't dump out a copy of the saved session data every time you update `$_SESSION`. The session file is actually LOCKED by PHP when any particular process is using it.

You'd need to do:

```
while($i<99){
    session_start();  // start session
    $i++;
    $_SESSION['progress'] = $i;

    session_write_close();  // save session data, release session file lock

    sleep(...);
}
```

In other words, your code would never work, as your `running` script would keep the session open/locked, preventing `progress` from ever accessing it.

Comment: this working ,but still the output `($_SESSION['progress'])` is a fixed value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global var but the better in mind is make a static or singleton class

```
class counter {
  private $_progress=0;

  public static function doProgress() {
    $i=0;
    while($i<99){
    $i++;
    $this->_progress = $i;
    }
  }

  public static function getProgress() {
    return $this->_progress;
  }
```

so in progress.php do

```
 echo Counter::getProgress()
```

and in you javascript you must use setinterval() function in my mermory to call at intervaled time the process.php script

Comment: in `progress.php` we have not `class Counter` ,and if we define it again , it will be a new `class` . doesn't?

Comment: yep. It will be new address space, new process. So static variables won't be shared