# PHP responding to ajax when running a long script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, copy, progress-bar

I've asked a question at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26469682/php-responding-to-ajax-when-running-process/26469762) that **answered and working fine**,

but my problem is that when script running about  more than  4~5 seconds , all `ajax` requests not working at all until completing running script .

In fact I've using a progress to copy files and when I choose a large file ,  after 30% process the `ajax` not working to get percentage of progress .

If you check my question , you will understand what I've saying .

**Copy.php**

```
$f = mysql_query(" select * from `process` ");
$f = mysql_fetch_assoc($f);
$total_bytes_readed = $f['total-bytes-readed'];
$total_bytes = $f['total-bytes'];
$abort = $f['state'] == 'abort'?true:false;
$remote = fopen($src, 'r');
$local = fopen($des, 'w');
$filesize = filesize($src);
$d = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$B = $speed = $time_remaining = $read_bytes = 0;

while(!feof($remote) && !$abort) {

    $field = mysql_query(" select * from `process` ");
    $field = mysql_fetch_assoc($field);
    if($field['state']=='abort')
    {
        fclose($remote);
        fclose($local);
        if(file_exists($des))
        unlink($des);
        $abort = true;
        return;
    }else{
        $bitrate = 2048*2048;
        $buffer = fread($remote, $bitrate);
        fwrite($local, $buffer);
        $read_bytes += $bitrate ;
        $total_bytes_readed += $bitrate;
        $D = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));        
        if($D-$d >=1)
        {
            $d = $D;
            $speed = $read_bytes - $B;
            $B = $read_bytes;
            $total_bytes_remaining = $total_bytes - $total_bytes_readed;
            $time_remaining = $total_bytes_remaining/$speed;
        }
        mysql_query("UPDATE `process` SET 
                    `total-bytes-readed` = '$total_bytes_readed',
                    `speed` = '$speed',
                    `time-remaining` = '$time_remaining' 
                     WHERE `process`.`id` =1");         
    }
}
fclose($remote);
fclose($local);
mysql_query("UPDATE `process` SET 
            `total-bytes-readed` = '$total_bytes_readed',
            `speed` = '$speed',
            `time-remaining` = '$time_remaining' 
             WHERE `process`.`id` =1");
```

**progress.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['cancel']) && $_POST['cancel']==1)
mysql_query("UPDATE `process` SET `state` = 'abort' WHERE `process`.`id` =1");  

$f = mysql_query(" select * from `process` ");
$f = mysql_fetch_assoc($f);

$re = array('totalfiles'  => $f['total-files'],
            'totalbytes'  => $f['total-bytes'],
            'bytesreaded' => $f['total-bytes-readed'],
            'file'        => $f['file'],
            'from'        => $f['from'],
            'to'          => $f['to'],
            'speed'       => ByteToSize($f['speed'])."/Second",
            'time'        => seconds_to_time($f['time-remaining']),
            'items'       => $f['items-remaining'],
            'state'       => $f['state'],
            );
echo json_encode($re);
```

**JS**

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.post( progress.php,{cancel:cancel_val},
    function(data){
       //...        
    }); 
},300);
```

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: Okay , please wait ...

Comment: in your browser what are the XHR requests returning when it starts to fail? is your copy script hitting it's max execution time, or running out of memory? what do your php error logs say?

Comment: there is no error , just `ajax` hanging

Comment: what happens if you set your interval to `1000`

Comment: Possibly the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675304/php-site-is-waiting-on-ajax-calls-to-complete/25675688#25675688, i.e you need to use session_write_close

Comment: set interval to 1000 just shows `50%` then `100%`

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing it in action, I would guess that the problem is that you have multiple ajax requests that are overlapping.

Instead of using an `setInterval`, you should set use a `setTimeout` in the success function of your ajax call. That way you ensure that there is always only 1 ajax request at most at the same time.

So your javascript would be something like:

```
function updateProgress() {
    $.post( progress.php,{cancel:cancel_val},
    function(data){
       //... 
       setTimeout(updateProgress, 300);      
    }); 
};

updateProgress();
```

Comment: @Damon.s Any messages in the console?

Comment: anythings not working , for example liking posts or comments in other posts because of ajax ...

Comment: @Damon.s Sounds like a syntax error somewhere, check the console.

Comment: nope . I'm sure about this . code running for a few seconds then stop and when copying has been completed the result shown .

Comment: @Damon.s Are you using sessions?